# Mongoose - problem with setting unique id

Tags: mongoose, duplicates, nestjs, uniqueidentifier

Creating schema in mongoose with unique field stopped working.
When creating new item, I'm getting error:
E11000 duplicate key error collection: xxx index: progressId_1 dup key: { progressId: "someValue" }

My schema looks like this:

```
@Schema()
export class Student {
....
 @Prop({
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        default: makeid(15),
        immutable: true
    }) progressId: string;
}


function makeid(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
            charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I;ve discovered that makeid is always returning same id. But when I run my makeid standalone then it's working fine - each time generating some random value.